# Asking for legitimate example of calling stored procedure C#: MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2015

I've spent about 7 hours trying to figure this out by trial and error. All the online examples I have seen either don't work, or dont apply, or only show half of what Im looking for.

Here is what I'm asking for:
1. An example of a simple stored procedure in MYSQL using one IN parameter and one OUT parameter.
2. An example of a FUNCTIONING (really important, cause online examples havent worked sometimes...) call from Visual Studio, using C#. Either a text call or stored procedure command type work.
3. AddWithValue has been deprecated.
4. I would love to see the out parameter actually work.

If this is impossible with MYSQL and visual studio, that would be nice to know as well.

MYSQL documentation is not thorough enough for this particular example. And pls, no Visual Studio or C# hatred.

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT:

This is what I have managed to do so far, and it DOES NOT WORK!!!

MYSQL side, using HeidiSQL:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `login`(IN `stuff` VARCHAR(50), IN `pass` VARCHAR(50), OUT `param3` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    set param3 = 0;
    set param3 = (select count(*) from users where username=stuff and userpassword=pass);
    select @param3;

END
```

And in C# side, I attempt to get this OUT parameter. Now, this is after multiple iterations, where I have gutted what the function used to be, and boiled it down to two issues: 1. The OUT parameters won't work, and 2. Even though Visual studio passes IN parameters, SQL refuses to recognize them.

```
protected void Login_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            con.Open();

            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("CALL login(@stuff, @pass, @param3);", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@stuff", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            com.Parameters["@stuff"].Value = Login.UserName;
            com.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            com.Parameters["@pass"].Value = Login.Password;

            try
            {
                obj = com.ExecuteScalar();
                objparam = com.Parameters["param3"].Value;
                if (Convert.ToInt32(obj) != 0)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    Login.PasswordRequiredErrorMessage = "invalid user name and password";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start over with an [edit] as your Q is about to close. Show the *closest* you have come up with.

Comment: I've edited to show my current iteration of what won't work. This is the closest i've come up with.

Comment: Thank you for showing what you have tried. That particular question is difficult to put together as a solution. Note, the MySQL .NET connector recently added the functionality to handle `OUT` parameters. How long ago, I do not know. So, I am using the lastest connector `version 6.9.9.0` at the moment.

Comment: Oh... That explains why examples and docs are nonexistent. Yay bleeding edge!lol

Comment: I have a doc reference: [5.10.1 Using Stored Routines from Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-using.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up a reference to the parameter

```
var param3 = new MySqlParameter();
param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
param3.DbType = // whatever the dbtype for int is or whatever you need.
param3.ParameterName = "param3";

com.Parameters.Add(param3);
```

in your try block, insert

```
var result = com.ExecuteReader(); // or com.ExecuteScalar();
```

after you execute that, your parameter should have the value populated and you should be able to also read the SP results (select).

```
var paramResult = param3.Value;
```

Reading the results of the SP can be done as reader or scalar.

```
// execute reader
while (result.Read()) {
    int value = result.GetInt32(0)); 
} /* read returned values in result */ 

// execute scalar
int value;
if (int.TryParse($"{result}", out value)) {
    /* do something with value */ 
}
```

/************************************************/

This block should get you where you need to go

```
        const string strcon = "whatevs";

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            const string sql = "login";

            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var stuffParam = new MySqlParameter("stuff", stuffValue);
            var passParam = new MySqlParameter("pass", passValue);
            var param3Param = new MySqlParameter();
            param3Param.ParameterName = "param3";
            param3Param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            param3Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            com.Parameters.Add(stuffParam);
            com.Parameters.Add(passParam);
            com.Parameters.Add(param3Param);

            try
            {
                var scalarResult = com.ExecuteScalar();

                // because you used select @param3 in your sp.
                int value;
                if (int.TryParse($"{scalarResult}", out value))
                {
                    //do something with value
                }

                //// because you used select @param3 in your sp.
                //var readerResult = com.ExecuteReader();

                //if (readerResult.Read())
                //{
                //    // 
                //    value = readerResult.GetInt32(0);
                //}

                int param3Returned;
                if(int.TryParse($"{param3Param.Value}", out param3Returned))
                {
                    // do something with param3Returned
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // do something with ex
            }
        }
```

Comment: This looks pretty close to what what probably would work. I'm hacking up my code now. Thank you!

What is scalarResult a property of? Intellisense says it doesnt exist.

Comment: Oh, ignore the last question about scalar result.

Comment: I think I'm super close now to the answer. I used your code and everything, but now it's giving me a new error. It's saying, 

Exception during execution of : 'login' Parameter 'stuff' is not defined.

As soon as I executeScalar or executeReader.

Comment: I have updated the code for parameter definition - @ symbol is not needed. Sorry.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I put so many hours into trying to figure this out! Removing the @ did it.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the code and the pictures say more than I ever will.

C# DB Layer (DB Layer has `conn` as a connection string):

```
// Note: this is an instance (myDB in terms of the GUI Object)

using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
...
...
public long MultBySeven(long theNum)
{   // Call a Mysql Stored Proc named "multBy7"
    // which takes an IN parameter, Out parameter (the names are important. Match them)
    // Multiply the IN by 7 and return the product thru the OUT parameter

    long lParam = 0;
    using (MySqlConnection lconn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
        lconn.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = lconn;
            cmd.CommandText = "multBy7"; // The name of the Stored Proc
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // It is a Stored Proc

            // Two parameters below. An IN and an OUT (myNum and theProduct, respectively)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myNum", theNum); // lazy, not specifying ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theProduct", MySqlDbType.Int32);
            cmd.Parameters["@theProduct"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; // from System.Data
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // let it rip
            Object obj = cmd.Parameters["@theProduct"].Value;
            lParam = (Int32)obj;    // more useful datatype
        }
    }
    return (lParam);
}
```

C# GUI Test Layer:

```
private void btnTestInOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   // This GUI Layer call thru the use of a business object or data layer object (`myDB`)
    long localHere = myDB.MultBySeven(11);
}
```

Stored Procedure (take a number, multiply by 7):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS multBy7;
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE multBy7
(   IN myNum INT,
    OUT theProduct INT
)
BEGIN
    SET theProduct=myNum*7;
END$
DELIMITER ;
```

Debug View (read: it works. 11x7=77):

[image]

**`MySQL Connector 6.9.9.0` / `Visual Studio 2015`**:
[image]

See also [5.10.1 Using Stored Routines from Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-using.html), age unknown.

Comment: Thanks to you I realized that I hadn't installed all the packages necessary. On top of fixing the code, I had to NuGet mysql Web, entity framework, and connector. I thought I had done right before, but apparently not.