# Why does ODBC C# return empty string while using OUT parameter in Stored Procedure in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, odbc

I have a stored procedure with two OUT parameters 'test1' and test2' in MySQL running server 5.6

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure`(OUT test1 varchar(20),OUT test2 int)
    BEGIN
     SET test1 = 'testing variable 1';
     SET test2 = 3;
    END
```

I have ODBC driver 5.3 installed on my computer. I am using the following code to bind the parameters and get the output value:

```
   OdbcCommand cmdTest = new OdbcCommand();
   cmdTest.Connection = this.conn;
   cmdTest.CommandText = "{call test.test_procedure (?, ?)}";

   cmdTest.Parameters.Add(@"test1", OdbcType.VarChar, 20).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
   cmdTest.Parameters.Add(@"test2", OdbcType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

   cmdTest.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   using (OdbcDataReader returnRead = cmdTest.ExecuteReader())
   {
     while (returnRead.Read())
     {
      //Do something
     }
   }

   string test1 = cmdTest.Parameters[0].Value.ToString();
   string test2 = cmdTest.Parameters[1].Value.ToString();
```

However, the value for strings `test1` and `test2` in C# code are returned as empty strings. How can I get the values that I set in the stored procedure?

I have also tried `ExecuteNonQuery()` but it gives the same result. I know I am connecting to the database since I am able to use `SELECT` and `INSERT` with `ExecuteReader()`.

Comment: You need to use RETURN or SELECT test1,test2

Comment: @Shannon I thought MySQL does not allow RETURN. If I use SELECT test1, test2 then do I need an OUT parameter?

Comment: Nope -- return is fine in MySQL: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/loops/return.php

Comment: And no - you wouldn't need an out parameter in that case.

Comment: It's syntactically the same as SELECT AS

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger My mistake MySQL does not allow RETURN in Stored Procedure but in a Function. If I try to use RETURN in Stored Procedure I get the message "Object's DDL contains syntax errors"

Comment: You're right -- I had it confused with function because using OUT in a procedure is not usually done. May I ask - what's the purpose of using OUT? There's usually a much better way of doing it in a procedure.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger if you want a resultset, and some outs

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I am developing a program that communicates with the MySQL database to call a stored function or run sql commands. This program will be used by others as a wrapper to write and read from the database. I was hoping to create a more versatile function in C# so that I wont have to modify it later. OUT is not required now but I will have to go back to the code if we decide to use it.

Comment: I can get you an OUT via the .net mysql connector

Comment: @Drew Ahh.. here's the other problem. I am not sure if they will stick to MySQL or migrate it to another database.

Comment: Well here is the link (to an answer of mine) for the most up-to-date Oracle download of the .net mysql connector ... how to write to an OUT parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38706288 .... so it is the .net connector .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problems using OUT parameters using MySQL Odbc in C#, but it works for me using a select at the end of procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure`()
BEGIN
   DECLARE test1 varchar(50);
   DECLARE test2 int;

   SET test1 = 'testing variable 1';
   SET test2 = 3;

   SELECT test1,test2;
END $$
```

And the C# code:

```
OdbcCommand cmdTest = new OdbcCommand();
cmdTest.Connection = MyConnection;
cmdTest.CommandText = "call test.test_procedure()";

using (OdbcDataReader returnRead = cmdTest.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (returnRead.Read())
    {
        string test1 = returnRead.GetString(0); //'testing variable 1'
        int test2 = returnRead.GetInt32(1); //3
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know of the `GetString` and `GetInt32` method. If I have to return a result set along with the two out variables, do I have to `SELECT` a full outer join with `test1`, `test2` and the result set?

Comment: Yes, you can add more columns :) , or use a full select with joins and so.