# StoredProcedure Incorrect Number of Arguments (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a `StoredProcedure` that I created like this;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mysqladmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `Alerts_GetAlerts`(IN managerID INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, Type, EmpID, ManagerID, HolID
    FROM Alerts
    WHERE ManagerID = managerID;
END$$
```

I then try to call this from my C# code like so;

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(MySQLConStr))
{
    con.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Alerts_GetAlerts", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managerID", managerID);
        using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                var alert = new AlertsModel
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[0]),
                    Type = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[1]),
                    ManagerID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[2]),
                    EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[3]),
                    HolidayID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[4]),
                };
                AllAlerts.Add(alert);
            }
        }
    }
    return AllAlerts;
}
```

However I constantly get, `Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE sdcdatabase.Alerts_GetAlerts; expected 1, got 0` even though to me it appears I am passing the managerID argument through;

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managerID", managerID);`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try adding `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: it will look more like http://stackoverflow.com/a/38706288

Comment: Is managerID a variable of type integer? Do not use AddWithValue but use a specific overload of ParametersCollection.Add that allows you to specify the exact datatype of your parameter.

Comment: please run the profiler in SQL server and check what is passing through the command. is the way to identify this types of error.

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(MySQLConStr))
{
    con.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Alerts_GetAlerts(@managerID)", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managerID", managerID);
        using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                var alert = new AlertsModel
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[0]),
                    Type = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[1]),
                    ManagerID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[2]),
                    EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[3]),
                    HolidayID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[4]),
                };
                AllAlerts.Add(alert);
            }
        }
    }
    return AllAlerts;
}
```

Comment: I must be blind. What's the difference between this code and the one OP supplied?

Comment: This line using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Alerts_GetAlerts(@managerID)", con))

Comment: oh I see.. I didn't expect that :

Comment: Parameter name must be defined inside stored procedure. Adding parameter name should solve the issue.